# How do I set column names in dynamic tables?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am retrieving a result from the database where the column names are `script_id`, `script_name` etc, now what I am doing is after fetching the results from the table say I fetched 2 columns, example `script_id` and `script_name` so am saving the names separated with a comma and using a loop, but what if I am not aware how many parameters the user has selected, and how many will it return? for example what am doing

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <?php
    $columns = explode(',', $fetch_column_list);
    foreach($columns as $throw_names) {
         echo '<td>'.$throw_names.'</td>';
     }
   ?>
  </tr>
 //And here I loop the results
</table>
```

But what If am having a form with different parameters to select
So here I cannot have a pre-defined list of my defined column names as user may or may not have seleted the column

So how I can generate the table dynamically with  MY DEFINED COLUMN HEADERS on the front-end

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know how many columns you've got.
Instead of numbers you have to use field names

```
<?
$trans = array (
    'script_name'  => 'Fancy script name field header',
    'script_value' => 'Fancy script value  field header',
}
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table");
$keys = array_keys($data[0]);
?>
<table>
  <tr>
<? foreach ($keys as $k): ?>
    <td><?=$trans[$k]?></td>
<? endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
  <tr>
<?     foreach ($row as $one): ?>
    <td><?=$one?></td>
<?     endforeach ?>
  </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you fetch your data?

If you use a function like [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), you may use

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( ... );
$columns = array_keys($row)
```

Comment: I know that, but how do I rename those keys?

Comment: Do you have a naming convetion (based on the column name), or a full list of possible column names? For the second, you can select then using a foreach on $columns. For the first, it depends on your naming convention

Comment: If I know how many columns am going to retrieve I am simply using a loop for comma separated column names which I've defined, but If I don't know how many columns will a user get, because that query will be generated according to the parameters the user has selected so here I cannot pre-define my column names